# Why does Moshi not use my custom adapter?

Tags: kotlin, moshi

We have a polymorphic behaviour, and to cater it with deserialisation, we have written a custom Moshi adapter for it.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
open class Field
```

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Field1 (
    @Json(name = "name")
    val name: String
): Field()
```

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Field2 (
    @Json(name = "address")
    val address: String
): Field()
```

The above is a very simplified version of what we are doing. We would like to use Moshi generated adapter for child classes (`Field1` and `Field2`) and this custom adapter only delegates the fromJson based on the available fields. Here is the custom adapter for `Field`:

```
class FieldAdapter {
    var moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()
    @ToJson
    fun toJson(field: Field): String {
        return ""
    }

    @FromJson
    fun fromJson(json: String): Field {
        val jsonObject = gson.fromJson(json, JsonObject::class.java)
        var field: Field? = null

        if (jsonObject.has("name")) {
            val field1JsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Field1> = moshi.adapter(Field1::class.java)
            field = field1JsonAdapter.fromJson(json)
        } else if (jsonObject.has("address")) {
            val field2JsonAdapter: JsonAdapter<Field2> = moshi.adapter(Field2::class.java)
            field = field2JsonAdapter.fromJson(json)
        }

        field?.let {
            return it
        }

        throw JsonDataException("Not a valid field JSON")
    }
}
```

The following test does not work:

```
@Test
fun testField1Serialization() {
    val json = MockResponseFileReader("field1.json").content

    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(FieldAdapter()).build()
    val adapter = moshi.adapter(Field::class.java)

    val field = adapter.fromJson(json)

    val field1 = field as Field1
    assertEquals("abc", field1.name)
}
```

The above test does not call the fromJson of our custom adapter, however if we change `val adapter = moshi.adapter(Field::class.java)` to `val adapter = FieldAdapter()` (to hardcode the custom adapter), it works.

Can you please guide what are we doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: seems fine to me, could you post field1.json and the error returned by the test?

Comment: @NicolaGallazzi yeah, I had tried a lot of things but it did not work. Before giving up, I tried implementing `JsonAdapter` and it just worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone facing the same issue, just implement `JsonAdapter` (toJson and fromJson methods) in your custom JSON adapater and it will just work.

Unfortunately, I still don't have an answer to why the adapter from original question would not work since this is how it is done in their official documentation.

Comment: Worked in my case, It was driving me nuts. An additional note is that when you implement this you still have to keep the `@FromJson` and `@ToJson` annotations

Answer (score 2):

Moshi’s adapters are ordered by precedence, so you always want to add the Kotlin adapter after your own custom adapters. Otherwise the `KotlinJsonAdapterFactory` will take precedence and your custom adapters will not be called.

```kotlin
Moshi.Builder()
       .add(MyCustomAdapter())
       .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
       .build()
```